# Making a fixed div scroll scroll with the page. (squarespace)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a banner in the top left corner that stays put and does not disappear or get cut off when the window shrinks. This is the site: indigolubricants.com and it can be accessed with the password: indigodenver . This is a squarespace site and some things behave differently than regular html and css.
HTML:
`<div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">Hover over symbols to see product categories</div>`

This is the css with the position as fixed. The problem with this is that I want the ribbon to scroll with the rest of the page. Please let me know of any solutions. Either css or javascript. I have already tried changing the position properties. If the element is absolute then I can't move it. Other elements get cut off when the page is resized.
CSS:

```
/* The ribbons */
.corner-ribbon{
    width: 1000px;
    background: #DAA520;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.corner-ribbon.shadow{
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
/* Different positions */
.corner-ribbon.top-left{
    top: 200px;
    left: -300px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying these styles to the element you want to fix. You can change the height and width accordingly.

```
height: 20vh;
width: 10vw;
top: 0;
position: fixed;
```